# How are SaaS applications organized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, saas

Consider web (MVC, for example Rails) application for multiple clients as a service.

How to design this?

- one application instance per client? (+ one database per client)
- one instance for all clients (+ one database for all clients)

Former one is simple, but... "inefficient". How about the latter? (best practices, design patterns)  How to separate client data? For example: worker "A" of client "1" has two documents, worker "B" of client "2" has three documents. How to build model associations to protect other users (and clients) data? I think joining every query with Client model is not a good solution.

Comment: Ideally, your models would all inherently be aware of client-ness.

Comment: I would say it is not as easy as that. There are many possibilities, but it really depends on use case what is desirable. I would suggest you looking at how Heroku works, there are some interviews, look at InfoQ for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at an [earlier response on multi-tenant apps in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413439/should-i-use-multiple-databases).

It really depends on your use case, but the simplest way to handle this is a single database with scoping to particular applications. You can head from there depending on your requirements/budget.

I am a big fan of the postgresql schema system detailed in that link :P

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) article explains multi-tenant data architectures well.

Probably obvious but I'll note it anyway; the default configuration of Rails instances to store session information client-side in cookies lends itself to having all application instances equally able to service requests.

[Another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479069.aspx) in the series is also informative in terms of identifying shared services such as monitoring that you will need.